# ADO.NET Data provider for Firebird in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, firebird

I am struggling creating a Firebird connection in Visual Studio 2015. I have a C# class library with which I would like to connect to a Firebird database.
I installed these plugins from NuGet:

[image]

But when I try to add a new Item "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" with "EF Designer from database", the Firebird connection is not listed:
[image]

Reading articles on the internet showed that an entry in machine.config should have been made. But this didn't happen. There is no Firebird entry in that config file.

The "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" reference exists in the Visual Studio project.

The entry in the App.config file is:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I as well installed the SQLite plugins just to see if this provider behaves the same. And indeed it wasn't listed either in the "Choose Data Source" dialog. I guess I make a general mistake.

Can anybody help me with this issue? How can I create a database connection to my Firebird database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the driver via NuGet, it is only available in your project, you can't use it from Visual Studio itself, as the NuGet package doesn't install itself on your machine (and so doesn't modify the machine.config).

You will need to install the driver and the DDEX provider (version 3.0.2 or higher) with the installers you can download from [Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider downloads](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Installing the FirebirdClient for the whole system added an entry to the machine.config but unfortunately didn't solve the problem. According to http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/news/ddex-provider-3-0-1-for-firebird-released-38018/ the DDEX provider is not for VS2015. The download link on that page simply refers to the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient from NuGet.

Comment: @telandor I suggest you also ask this on the Firebird.net provider mailinglist; I don't regularly use Visual Studio so I don't know all the ins and outs of getting this to work.

Comment: the DDEX provider supports VS2015

Comment: @telandor I have doublechecked, you need to install both the driver and DDEX provider and it will work in VS2015. The news item you are linking to is from 2014, when VS2015 didn't exist yet. I will update the description on the additional downloads page to reflect that it also works on VS2015.

Comment: Thank you. I now have installed FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.10.0 (NuGet), EntityFramework.Firebird 4.10.0 (NuGet), DDEX provider 3.0.1 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%203.0.1/) and FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.10.0.0 (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/).
Unfortunately it still doesn't work. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: Have you tried the latest DDEX provider installer, 3.0.2, that is downloadable from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/ . 3.0.1 was released before Visual Studio 2015 existed, so it is likely not supported.

Comment: I just figured this out too. I had 3.0.1 installed. With 3.0.2 it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work. It seems that the ADO.NET provider for Firebird 3 has been compiled with Visual Studio 2017 (with C# 7.0 features) and I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Because some tools we're using we can't upgrade to 2017 easily.